# LINQ query on a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, .net-3.5

I'm trying to perform a LINQ query on a DataTable object and bizarrely I am finding that performing such queries on DataTables is not straightforward. For example:

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable
where results.Field("RowNo") == 1
select results;
```

This is not allowed. How do I get something like this working?

I'm amazed that LINQ queries are not allowed on DataTables!

Comment: You can find more LINQ/Lambda example from 

http://webmingle.blogspot.com/2010_09_01_archive.html

Comment: It's because datatables predate LINQ by some number of years. Use a strongly typed datatable instead; a better experience all round than this stringly-typed, intellisense-defeating `dt.Rows["FirstName]` junk.. With a strongly typed table (add a DataSet type file to your project and create tables inside it in the visual designer) you just write e.g. `myStronglyTpedDataset.Person.Where(p => p.FirstName == "John")` - all the magic to make it happen is already done

Comment: @CaiusJard does that mean that you would have to create DataSet type file for every query?

Comment: Not for every query, no. The dataset represents the entities being modelled, so in the same way that you might have an Order entity that has a list of Product entity in an EF application, your strongly typed dataset has a OrdersDataTable that has a relation to a ProductsDataTable. It's similar effort to create them too if you have a DB, as EF can scaffold entities from an existing db, as can the dataset designer. If you were adding new entities to your code it's slightly easier with datasets; you just click click add a table, click add columns etc and in the background VS is writing your code

Comment: So all that's necessary here is one `AsEnumerable()` call. No idea why that requires so many answers.

Answer (score 1413, accepted):

You can't query against the `DataTable`'s *Rows* collection, since `DataRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to use the `AsEnumerable()` extension for `DataTable`. Like so:

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
select myRow;
```

And as [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893/5519709) says, you'll need to add a reference to [System.Data.DataSetExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)

`AsEnumerable()` returns `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. If you need to convert `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to a `DataTable`, use the `CopyToDataTable()` extension.

Below is query with Lambda Expression,

```
var result = myDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(myRow => myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1);
```

Comment: VB Version:
           Dim results = From myRow In myDataTable.AsEnumerable _
                Where myRow.Field("RowNo") = 1 _
                Select myRow

Comment: I already had a reference to the dll mentioned, but was missing `using System.Data;`

Comment: How do I get DataTable back from var results ?

Comment: VB Version needs to insert (Of String) between myRow.Field and ("RowNo"). That part should read: myRow.Field(Of String)("RowNo") = 1  - Reference @Cros comment.

Comment: this solution is needlessly complicated. Use `myDataTable.Rows` instead as @JoelFan suggested.

Comment: @Markus Just to clarify, the reason that @JoelFan's solution works with `myDataTable.Rows` is because the `myRow` variable is explicitly cast to `DataRow`. When it is compiled, that query is rewritten to `myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(myRow => (int)myRow["RowNo"] == 1)`. Personally, I don't find the call to `AsEnumerable()` any more complicated than the call to `Cast<DataRow>()`. As far as I know, the performance is the same, so it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: `...If you need to convert IEnumerable<DataRow> to aDataTable, use the CopyToDataTable() extension.` this I have ben searching for ;)

Comment: is it faster than using for loop ?

Answer (score 141):

```
var results = from DataRow myRow in myDataTable.Rows
    where (int)myRow["RowNo"] == 1
    select myRow
```

Comment: What about for selecting multiple rows, instead of just row 1?

Comment: Just remove the "where" line and you will get all the rows

Comment: Yes, this is how I use to do it, except for replacing `(int)myRow["RowNo"]` with the generic form `myRow.Field<int>("RowNo")` to more conveniently support nullable types.

Answer (score 75):

It's not that they were deliberately not allowed on DataTables, it's just that DataTables pre-date the IQueryable and generic IEnumerable constructs on which Linq queries can be performed.

Both interfaces require some sort type-safety validation. DataTables are not strongly typed. This is the same reason why people can't query against an ArrayList, for example.

For Linq to work you need to map your results against type-safe objects and query against that instead.

Answer (score 54):

As @ch00k said:

```
using System.Data; //needed for the extension methods to work

...

var results = 
    from myRow in myDataTable.Rows 
    where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1 
    select myRow; //select the thing you want, not the collection
```

You also need to add a project reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Comment: If you try this, you'll find it won't work unless you put a specific type on `myRow` or use `Cast<DataRow>()` on `Rows`. Better to use `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @NetMage this worked 12 years ago when I posted it. As long as you have `System.Linq` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` then `myDataTable.Rows` returns an enumerable collection of `DataRow` anyway. That might have changed, it's been a decade since I've used it.

Comment: Interesting - I guess it was changed at some point, as it doesn't work on .Net or .Net Core now.

Comment: @NetMage yes, I'm not surprised the `DataSet` extensions didn't make it into .NET Core or .NET Standard, they were already outdated when I posted this answer. I really wouldn't use `DataSet` in new projects, there are far better data access models, both for ease of coding and performance.

Comment: They are there, but `DataRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` just `IEnumerable` and so doesn't work with strongly typed LINQ.

Answer (score 47):

I realize this has been answered a few times over, but just to offer another approach:

I like to use the `.Cast<T>()` method, it helps me maintain sanity in seeing the explicit type defined and deep down I think `.AsEnumerable()` calls it anyways:

```cs
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
                  where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1 select myRow;
```

or

```cs
var results = myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1);
```

*As noted in comments, does not require `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` or any other assemblies ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast))*

Comment: This works without referencing System.Data.DataSetExtensions.

Answer (score 40):

```
var query = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where p.Field<string>("code") == this.txtCat.Text
                    select new
                    {
                        name = p.Field<string>("name"),
                        age= p.Field<int>("age")                         
                    };
```

the name and age fields are now part of the query object and can be accessed like so: **Console.WriteLine(query.name);**

Comment: How I use name? For example, `MessageBox.Show(name)` is undefined.

Answer (score 34):

[Using LINQ to manipulate data in DataSet/DataTable](http://dotnetarchitect.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/using-linq-to-manipulate-data-in-datasetdatatable/)

```
var results = from myRow in tblCurrentStock.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("item_name").ToUpper().StartsWith(tbSearchItem.Text.ToUpper())
              select myRow;
DataView view = results.AsDataView();
```

Comment: The AsDataView doesn't appear in Intellisense for me. I included using System.Data.Linq and using System.Linq but still it's not working. Do you know what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Naomi It comes from `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Answer (score 30):

```
//Create DataTable 
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
{
   new DataColumn("ID",typeof(System.Int32)),
   new DataColumn("Name",typeof(System.String))

});

//Fill with data

dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{1,"Test1"});
dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{2,"Test2"});

//Now  Query DataTable with linq
//To work with linq it should required our source implement IEnumerable interface.
//But DataTable not Implement IEnumerable interface
//So we call DataTable Extension method  i.e AsEnumerable() this will return EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>


// Now Query DataTable to find Row whoes ID=1

DataRow drow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p=>p.Field<Int32>(0)==1).FirstOrDefault();
 //
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this simple line of query:

```
var result=myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(myRow => myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use LINQ to objects on the Rows collection, like so:

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.Rows where myRow.Field("RowNo") == 1 select myRow;
```

Comment: Because `DataTable.Rows` does not implement `IEnumerable`, I can't see how this query could compile.

Comment: @onedaywhen I just saw this being done in some code and it does compile. Trying to figure out why right now.

Comment: ... or you can just use a filter expression within the Select method : var results = myDataTable.Select("RowNo=1"); This returns a DataRow array.

Answer (score 14):

This is a simple way that works for me and uses lambda expressions:

```
var results = myDataTable.Select("").FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x["RowNo"] == 1)
```

Then if you want a particular value:

```
if(results != null) 
    var foo = results["ColName"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
var row = (from result in dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy( result => Guid.NewGuid()) select result).Take(3) ;
```

Answer (score 11):

Most likely, the classes for the DataSet, DataTable and DataRow are already defined in the solution. If that's the case you won't need the DataSetExtensions reference.

Ex. DataSet class name-> CustomSet, DataRow class name-> CustomTableRow (with defined columns: RowNo, ...)

```
var result = from myRow in myDataTable.Rows.OfType<CustomSet.CustomTableRow>()
             where myRow.RowNo == 1
             select myRow;
```

Or (as I prefer)

```
var result = myDataTable.Rows.OfType<CustomSet.CustomTableRow>().Where(myRow => myRow.RowNo);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable
where results.Field<Int32>("RowNo") == 1
select results;
```

Comment: This answer as a lot of issues with it.

Answer (score 8):

In my application I found that using LINQ to Datasets with the AsEnumerable() extension for DataTable as suggested in the answer was extremely slow.  If you're interested in optimizing for speed, use James Newtonking's Json.Net library (http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

```
// Serialize the DataTable to a json string
string serializedTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDataTable);    
Jarray dataRows = Jarray.Parse(serializedTable);

// Run the LINQ query
List<JToken> results = (from row in dataRows
                    where (int) row["ans_key"] == 42
                    select row).ToList();

// If you need the results to be in a DataTable
string jsonResults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
DataTable resultsTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonResults);
```

Comment: I doubt this is faster, in the general cases. It has the overhead of two serialization, one deserialization and one parsing operations. Regardless, I downvoted because it is not concise, i.e. the serialization/deserialization doesn't make clear that the intent is to filter a list.

Comment: @an phu, using the .AsEnumerable extension method creates a collection of heavyweight `System.Data.DataRow` objects. The serialized and parsed data table creates lightweight data consisting only of the column names and values of each row.  When the query runs, it will load the data into memory, which for a large dataset may involve swapping.  Sometimes, the overhead of several operations is less than the overhead of copying large amounts of data in and out of memory.

Answer (score 8):

Example on how to achieve this provided below:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); //Create a dataset
dataSet = _DataEntryDataLayer.ReadResults(); //Call to the dataLayer to return the data

//LINQ query on a DataTable
var dataList = dataSet.Tables["DataTable"]
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(i => new
              {
                 ID = i["ID"],
                 Name = i["Name"]
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

For VB.NET The code will look like this:

```
Dim results = From myRow In myDataTable  
Where myRow.Field(Of Int32)("RowNo") = 1 Select myRow
```

Answer (score 7):

```
IEnumerable<string> result = from myRow in dataTableResult.AsEnumerable()
                             select myRow["server"].ToString() ;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "Select * from Employee",con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader( );
DataTable dt = new DataTable( "Employee" );
dt.Load( dr );
var Data = dt.AsEnumerable( );
var names = from emp in Data select emp.Field<String>( dt.Columns[1] );
foreach( var name in names )
{
    Console.WriteLine( name );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get it work elegant via linq like this:

```
from prod in TenMostExpensiveProducts().Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
where prod.Field<decimal>("UnitPrice") > 62.500M
select prod
```

Or like dynamic linq this (AsDynamic is called directly on DataSet):

```
TenMostExpensiveProducts().AsDynamic().Where (x => x.UnitPrice > 62.500M)
```

I prefer the last approach while is is the most flexible.
P.S.: Don't forget to connect `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` reference

Answer (score 5):

you can try this, but you must be sure the type of values for each Column

```
List<MyClass> result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new MyClass(){
     Property1 = (string)x.Field<string>("ColumnName1"),
     Property2 = (int)x.Field<int>("ColumnName2"),
     Property3 = (bool)x.Field<bool>("ColumnName3"),    
});
```

Comment: Has the world gone mad?  Whats wrong with sql?
    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("id=1");
Maybe this is too easy.

Answer (score 0):

I propose following solution:

```
DataView view = new DataView(myDataTable); 
view.RowFilter = "RowNo = 1";
DataTable results = view.ToTable(true);
```

Looking at the [DataView Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.8), the first thing we can see is this:

> Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation.

What I am getting from this is that DataTable is meant to only store data and DataView is there enable us to "query" against the DataTable.

Here is how this works in this particular case:

You try to implement the SQL Statement

```
SELECT *
FROM myDataTable
WHERE RowNo = 1
```

in "DataTable language". In C# we would read it like this:

```
FROM myDataTable
WHERE RowNo = 1
SELECT *
```

which looks in C# like this:

```
DataView view = new DataView(myDataTable);  //FROM myDataTable
view.RowFilter = "RowNo = 1";  //WHERE RowNo = 1
DataTable results = view.ToTable(true);  //SELECT *
```

Comment: This isn't really true at all I'm afraid. DataView are useful but they aren't intended to implement the sophisticated sorts of data operations LINQ does