# LINQPad still cannot find extension method 'Where' after adding System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Tags: linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have to join results from 2 sprocs in LINQ but got the error message:
'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

However after added the DataSetExtensions the error still appears.

Code:

```
var c = GetAllGameCategories (123);
var d = GetGameCategories(22458);

Var e = c.Where(....);  // Error on this line!
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Comment: Got 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Am I suppose to find way to cast or convert result set of sproc query into DataTable as always?

Comment: the DataSet is a collection of DataTables, you must choose which table you want to query. You can get a DataTable from a DataSet using the index operator on the Tables collection i.e. myDataSet.Tables[0]

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSet` is a collection of `DataTable` objects.
It does not directly contain any data.

You need to call `.Where()` on the Data*Table*.
**EDIT**: If it isn't a typed DataTable, you'll need to call `.AsEnumerable()` first.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, appreciated for your help.

Comment: The result is from SPROC query, sorry I didn't explicitly state what exactly the type it is, but from LINQPad I got the impression that its treated as DataSet by default.  I was using LINQPad to test out my lambdas but at the end I use the .ToArray() to both c and d back in the code as a work around.

Comment: foreach (var item in c)
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in d)
                    {
                        if (item.ID == item2.ID)
                        {
                            return item.ShortDescription.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Return a null string if match failed.
                return null;