# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The error is shown at select when i write next LINQ query:

```
DataTable dtbl = //...
int count = (from p in dtbl select p.RecordID).Max();
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
int count = dtbl.Max(p => p.RecordID);
```

**Edit:**

You can't easily use Linq on a `DataTable`.

See: [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Comment: isn't that just rewriting it :D?

Comment: @The_Butcher: It is and is better

Comment: @The_Butcher - no its not rewriting it. Its fixing the intention.

Comment: dtbl is a datatable. it is giving error "'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" when i add this line.

Comment: Try dtbl.AsEnumerable().Max(p => p.RecordID);

Comment: this link is helpful but i have done some rework thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment that dtbl is a DataTable you can do:

```
int count = dtbl.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("RecordID"));
```

You will need to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll and add a `using System.Data` directive to the source file.