# How to convert the following lines to Generic LINQ statements

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following lines of code in C#
 that gets data using DataTables
This is pretty generic and helps me with multiple tables.

```
object obj = ((DataRowView)editingElement.DataContext).Row[this.SelectedValuePath];
```

I want to change this statement to a generic LINQ statement so that i can use it with multiple LINQ tables too.

Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use LINQ to make the code you wrote nicer or more elegant in any way. I assume that the type of `editingElement.DataContext` is `object`, so you'll need to write the cast anyway. If you forget about the casting, your code is just indexed access:

```
var rows = (DataRowView)editingElement.DataContext;
object obj = rows.Row[this.SelectedValuePath];
```

LINQ doesn't have any features that would make indexing nicer, so I think this is the best you can get. One possible ugly thing is that you get `object` as the result and you'll need to cast that to some other type (e.g. `CustomerInfo`).

If you were using LINQ from the beginning (to populate the data for the `DataContext`), you could probably write something like this to access the customer:

```
var rows = (IEnumerable<CustomerInfo>)editingElement.DataContext;
CustomerInfo info = rows.Row[this.SelectedValuePath];
```

This would be a bit more elegant, because you'd need just a single cast. However, I think that your code is fine and LINQ cannot help you (in this piece of code).