# Linq not recognizing namespace

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently learning LINQ to SQL where I am selecting a data from the LINQ table object through datacontext.

I have created a datacontext by adding linqtosql class and dragged the HH_table.

The problem I'm facing is the LINQ namespace is not recognized by the program.

```
using (var connection = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
   var g = from a in HH_table select a.date;
}
```

In the above code i'm getting a error that:

> cannot resolve symbol 'select'.

I have added all the references with respect to LINQ

```
    System.Data.linq
    System.core,
    System.xml.linq
    System.Linq;
```

but none of the references solve the above problem.

Am I missing something?

Comment: have you declared `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672660/9020340

Comment: yes i declared both using System.Linq; and using System.data.Linq; both are unrecogonized by program. Tool tip says both the diretive are not used by the code.

Comment: What is `HH_table` and how does it relate to `connection`?

Comment: You haven't listed `using System.Linq;` in your usings list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the data context just before HH_table. Notice I renamed connection to context, just because that better reflects what it is.

```
using (var context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var g = from a in context.HH_table select a.date;
}
```

Comment: The `using System.Linq` is also required, just as Enigmativity said.

Comment: as u mentined i have missed to add the connection before table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System.Linq?

If you have errors like "cannot resolve System.Linq", check your .NET Framework version.
System.Linq was introduced on .NET Framework 3.5.

In visual studio, Go to Project -> Properties -> Application and check the "Target Framework" property. It's probably a target framework prior to 3.5.

also, you still may have problems because of HH_Table. if HH_Table is a table of your "connection" context, use "connection.HH_Table" instead.