# Using Field<> with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, field

I'm trying to pass a column name to a class and retrieve a value for that column from a sql database. Looks like Field<> is not available for a Table, but it will work with DataTable. Can someone point me how can i do it using linq? I'm sure it is a very simple thing. Thanks.

```
[Table(Name = "[Keys]")]
public class Keys
{
    [Column]
    public string Column_A{ get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Column_B{ get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Column_C{ get; set; }
}

    public string ReadKey(string DBKey)
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(sqlconn);
    Table<Keys> keysTable = dc.GetTable<Keys>();

    var query = from k in keysTable.AsEnumerable()
    select k.Field<string>("DBKey");     <---------------- wrong

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Field<>` is for LINQ to DataTables, and is included as an extension to System.Data.  It's not a standard LINQ extension method.  See this SO question on how to use [LINQ to DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable).

What you're trying to do can be accomplished by using an Expression, or [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  Dynamic LINQ is not part of what's shipped with .NET; it was included as an example in VS2008 and people have continued to use it.  I'm not sure if it's supported, updated, etc. by Microsoft.  I wouldn't count on it until it's incorporated into the framework.

You could create a method create the `selector` mentioned in Jon's answer as such:

```
public Expression<Func<Keys,T>> GetSelectLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression lhsParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Keys), "s");
    Expression fieldParam = Expression.Property(lhsParam, propertyName);
    var theExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Keys, T>>(fieldParam, lhsParam);
    return theExpression;
}
```

So passing in `GetSelectLambda<string>("DBKey")` should generate a lambda of `s => s.DBKey`, which is then returned and passed into Jon's method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You generally shouldn't use a column *name* with LINQ to SQL - one of the benefit of LINQ to SQL over using untyped `DataTable` objects is that you get more compile-time safety.

If you need to allow different columns to be selected, you can use an expression tree to select them:

```
public string ReadKey(Expression<Func<Keys, string>> selector)
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(sqlconn);
    Table<Keys> keysTable = dc.GetTable<Keys>();

    // Generally speaking you don't want to use AsEnumerable here...
    var query = keysTable.Select(selector);
    // Now do something with query
}
```

Note that using `GetTable` is *rarely* a great idea - normally you'd work with a specific table on a specific `DataContext`.