# Count concurrent Calls from Calllog

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

there is a list of Calls, with starttime, stoptime, duration, caller and some other Attributes. Now I try to visualize the concurrent Calls from this list, but I don't know how to start with this task. I want realize this task in .net C#.

First idea was to take each call, and count it to an Array for each second, then I have an array which counts the call for every second, but it is not so nice I think.

```
 class CallConcurrentCounterController
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        var Calls = new ImportDataFromCSV();
        DataTable dataTable = Calls.GetDataTable(Path,Seperator);

        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2011,07,01);            
        callsBucket(dataTable,startTime);            
    }
    public void callsBucket(DataTable Calls, DateTime startTime)
    {
        var callsBuckets =
            from time in Enumerable.Range(0, (60 * 24))
                .Select(i => startTime.AddMinutes(i)) // Create the times base on start time and current minute.                
            select new // Create an anonymous type
            {
                // Create a property called Time, that stores the time checked
                Time = time,
                // Another property that stores the number of calls happening at that time.
                //CallCount = Calls.Rows.Count(Call => Call.start <= time && Call.stop >= time)                    
                CallCount = Calls.AsEnumerable().Count
                    (Call => DateTime.Parse(Call.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " " + Call.ItemArray[1].ToString()) <= time && 
                             DateTime.Parse(Call.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " " + Call.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= time)
            };
    }
}
```

From the function who is calling this function is given a DataTable with n Rows each Row is a Call with the Attributes start ItemArray[1] (for start-Time), stop ItemArray[2] (for stop-Time), Date ItemArray[0] and some other Attributes such Caller-Number...

Now I get a bucket which counts the calls by minute. But how I can convert the Type of callsBuckets to an type like `Enumerable<dateTime,int>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started.
This creates minute windows (covering the whole day, 60 mins per hour, 24 hours per day) from a given start time.

It then counts all calls that start before, and finish after that time. You could change the `Count` call to a `Where`, to keep the details of the individual calls that were occurring during each time.

```
var startTime = new DateTime.Today().AddDays(-1); //When to start the minute interval buckets
var callsBuckets =
    from time in Enumerable.Range(0, (60 * 24) // Minutes in a day
                           .Select(i => new DateTime(startTime).AddMinutes(i) // Create the times base on start time and current minute.
    select new // Create an anonymous type
    {
        // Create a property called Time, that stores the time checked
        Time = time,
        // Another property that stores the number of calls happening at that time.
        CallCount = Calls.Count(Call => Call.StartTime <= time && Call.StopTime >= time)
    };
```

Now that you've shown you're using a `DataTable`, see the accepted answer to this question: [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable).

Comment: Using uppercase letters for variables is confusing.

Comment: Hi George, i test your code but get some errors, i read a CSV with Calls and write it to an DataTable called "Calls" then i init a Function with parameter: Calls, startTime, stopTime and write your Code inside, but i get a error that there is no function Count who accept DataRowCollection.

Comment: See my edit, i've added a link that should enable you to use my answer to query your datatable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by writing a method which determines whether two `DateTime` ranges overlap. Once that method is working, simply look for a call in your list that has the most number of overlaps. Alternatively, if you need to determine the number of calls *at a particular time*, simply write a method that checks whether the range covers this time value, and do a `Count()` on your list of calls.

Comment: Can you explain how i can check for range overlap of two DateTime Vars?

Comment: Something like this: `private bool intersects(int r1start, int r1end, int r2start, int r2end)
{
    return (r1start == r2start) || (r1start > r2start ? r1start <= r2end : r2start <= r1end);
}`