# LINQ Over a Dataset Error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to retrieve data form a dataset by using code below :

```
    var all_pepole = from rows_of_bank in ds1.Tables[0].Rows select rows_of_bank;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in all_pepole)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} years old.", row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString());
    }
```

But this codes will raise error for me and this is error :

**Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'rows_of_bank'**

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ds1.Tables[0].Rows` is of type `DataRowCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Most Linq operators work only on the generic interface. You can cast the items to `DataRow` like this:

```
var all_pepole = from rows_of_bank in ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>() select rows_of_bank;
```

Or you can use the `AsEnumerable` extension method from Linq to DataSets:

```
var all_pepole = from rows_of_bank in ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() select rows_of_bank;
```