# Get values from DataTable without data binding to UI controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, datatable

I always get values from the database directly to a control like this:

Code-behind:

```
DataTable table = GetUserInfo();

UserInfo.DataSource = table;
UserInfo.DataBind();

string FirstName = lblFirstName.Text;
string LastName = lblLastName.Text;
DateTime BecomeAMember = DateTime.Parse(lblBecomeAMember.Text);
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="lblBecomeAMember" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BecomeAMember", "{0:dd MMM yyy) %>' />
```

There has to be a way to use the data in code-behind without putting it to a label and then use `String text = label.Text;`

I need the minutes and hours from `BecomeAMember`, and I don't want to use another `Label` with the full `DateTime` and make it invisible. It would be nice to know how to get the other values as well.

Comment: As your controls have the runat=server set, can't you just assign the values to the label in the code behind and set the formatting accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `DataTable` methods to read values directly from the `table` object.

For instance,

```
string firstName = table.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
```

or

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    //
}
```

Or use Select() method to search on specified field.

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("column1='value1'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can directly investigate the data held in the `DataTable`.

[`DataTable` can be made into an `IEnumerable`, and can be queried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable) In your case:

```
var datetimes = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("BecomeAMember"));
```

If you really only expect a single row, you can do either:

```
var dt = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("BecomeAMember")).Single();
```

or:

```
var dt = (DateTime) table.Rows[0]["BecomeAMember"];
```

Then format `dt` using `ToString` with a format string.