# Difference of two DataTables in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two data tables as follows

```
dtOne
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  ABC
 102  |  XYZ
 103  |  MNO
--------------------------

dtTwo
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  ABC
 102  |  XYZ
--------------------------
```

I just want the result as data which is `in dtOne` and  `not in dtTwo` (dtOne-dtTwo)

```
dtResult
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 103  |  MNO
--------------------------
```

How can i achieve this .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TO get it work its better to use Linq To DataSet will resolve it easily..

```
DataTable table1= ds.Tables["table1"];
DataTable table2= ds.Tables["table2"];
var diff= table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the solution showed under [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable), I'd try it with:

```
var dtOneData = from myRow in dtOne.AsEnumerable();
var dtTwoData = from myRow in dtOne.AsEnumerable();
var difference = dtOneData.Except(dtTwoData);
```