# Compare two DataTables with several keys and select the rows that are not present in second table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two DataTables and I want to select the rows from the first one which are not present in second one, both tables have 3 Keys custnum, shiptonum, connum

For example:

Table Contacts

```
custnum  shiptonum  connum  column
   1        1         1     data1    
   2        2         2     data2
   3        3         3     data3
   4        4         4     data4
```

Table Invitations

```
custnum  shiptonum  connum  column
   1        1         1     data11
   3        3         3     data33
```

I'd like the result to be:

Table Result

```
custnum  shiptonum  connum  column
   2        2         2     data2
   4        4         4     data4
```

I already tried using

var differences = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);

but it didn't work. For example in my testing in Contacts table I have 14,389 records, in Invitations table I have two records that exist in Contacts table the count after using the abovesolution was 14,389 instead of 14,387 (removing the two records from Invitations table).

Comment: Possibly you need something like this: `var differences = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of two DataTables in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289475/difference-of-two-datatables-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It didn't work @TetsuyaYamamoto, for example in my testing in Contacts table I have 14,389 records, in table Invitations I have two records that exist in Contacts table the count after using the suggested solution was 14,389 instead of 14,387 (removing the two records from Invitations table).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I want to select the rows from the first one which are not present in second one

From your example, I see that you don't want to select rows from the first table that are not rows in the second table, but that you only want to take the values of the keys into account:

> I want to select all rows from `tableA` which have keys with values that are not keys from `tableB`

You didn't define your tables. They might be `IQueryable`, or `IEnumerable`, for your LINQ statements there is not a big difference. Try to avoid `AsEnumerable`, especially if your data source is in a different process, like a database management system. The other process is much more efficient in executing your query than your process. `AsEnumerable` transports all data from your other process to your process, which is a relatively slow process. Therefore as a rule: Only use `AsEnumerable` this if you really need to,

The second definition defines clearer what you want: apparently from `tableB` you only need the keys:

```
var keysTableB = tableB.Select(row => new
    {
         CustNum = row.custNum,
         ShipToNum = row.shiptonum,
         ConNum = row.connum,
    });
```

In words: from every row in tableB make one new object of anonymous type with three properties: `CustNum`, `ShipToNum` and `ConNum`

`Select` uses lazy execution. No query is executed, only property `Expression` is changed.

Now you want to keep only the rows from `tableA` that have a key that is a member of sequence `keysTableB`: if you want to keep a subset of a sequence, use `Where`

```
var result = tableA.Where(row => keysTableB.Contains(new
    {
         CustNum = row.custNum,
         ShipToNum = row.shiptonum,
         Connum = row.connum,
    }));
```

In words: from every row in tableB keep only those rows that have a key that is also in `keysTableB`, using value equality.

TODO: consider concatenating these two LINQ statements into one.
I doubt whether this would improve performance. It surely will deteriorate readability of your code, and thus decreases changeability / maintenance / testability.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<table1.rows.count;i++)
{
   var rowExists = from dr in table2.AsEnumerable()
                   where dr.Field<typeofcolumn>("colum_name")==table1.Rows[i]["column_name"]
                   select dr;
  if(rowExists.ToList().Count==0)
  {
      //here u import row table1.rows[i] to new table
  }
}
```