# datatable select rows

Tags: c#

I am using a datatable created by program. In this datatable i want to insert values in some specified columns.

Initially I am inserting primary key values leaving remaining columns null, when I am querying datatable with recently inserted value in Primary column to update same row, I am facing error  `Missing operand after ID operator`

Can any one tell me the exact issue.

I am trying following code:

```
 dt.Rows.Add(1);
 int insertedValue = 1;
 DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ID = '" + insertedValue.toString() + "'");
```

And the table structure after entring primary value is as follows.

```
ID    Volumn1    Volumn2    volumn3
--------------------------------------
1
```

Comment: If at all an option, you may want to take a look at [Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this more cleanly with LINQ and make this a strongly typed operation.

Something like:

```
dt.Rows.Add(1);
int insertedValue = 1;
var result = 
        dt.AsEnumerable().Where( dr => dr.Field<int>( "ID" ) == insertedValue );
```

Working example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add( "ID", typeof( int ) );
dt.Rows.Add( 1 );

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where( dr => dr.Field<int>( "ID" ) == 1 );
```

Comment: I have tried above in my code, this time i can see the var result properties where in message property it showing "Specified cast is not valid" @Tim Medora

Comment: @Pramod - see my updated example. Your columns need to be strongly-typed and the Where() method takes a generic parameter of the same type.

Comment: `result` contains an enumerable collection of data rows. You can use the `First()` method to get the first result.

Comment: But after using FIRST() i would have lost all the column names form source table...??? i  mean i cant update datatables current row for selected id for specified column(dynamic) @ Tim Medora.

Comment: `First()` will give you a DataRow back...same as `DataTable.Select()`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply format the selection string as shown below:

```
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select(string.Format("ID ='{0}' ", insertedValue));
```

Feel free to let me know if this works for you.. Thanks

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Comment: Note: This works great in conjunction with: foreach (DataRow r in dr) {... loops.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `' '` in your filter.

I think this should work:

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ID = " + insertedValue.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific row and your datatable has a primary key you could use the Find method and target the primary key which would return just the row you want rather than an array:

```
DataRow foundRow = dt.Rows.Find([INSERT SEARCH PARAMETER HERE]);
if(foundRow != null)
{
    TO SET A STRING EQUAL TO A FOUND VALUE:
    string str = foundRow["COLUMN NAME / INDEX];

    OR IF YOU ARE INSERTING A VALUE YOU CAN USE IT LIKE THIS:
    foundRow["COLUMN NAME / INDEX"] = NEW VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

select column of row

```
dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("MyColumnName")
```