# Querying Datatable with where condition

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with two columns,

```
Column 1 = "EmpID"
Column 2 = "EmpName"
```

I want to query the datatable, against the column `EmpID` and 
`Empname`.

For example, I want to get the values where

```
(EmpName != 'abc' or EmpName != 'xyz') and (EmpID = 5)
```

Comment: @QQping, i couldnt do it. No idea. Just started to query in datatable

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like this...

```
var res = from row in myDTable.AsEnumerable()
where row.Field<int>("EmpID") == 5 &&
(row.Field<string>("EmpName") != "abc" ||
row.Field<string>("EmpName") != "xyz")
select row;
```

See also 
[LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Comment: missied out, how can i get the count of number of rows returned. Thanks

Comment: sorry, i couldnt. I get this error when i convert res.count to Int...{"Specified cast is not valid."}{system.SystemException {System.InvalidCastException}

Comment: VB ex:
Dim result = From row In myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
   Where row.Field(Of Integer)("myColumn1") > 0 And row.Field(Of Integer)("myColumn2") > 0
   Select row

Answer (score 21):

You can do it with Linq, as mamoo showed, but the [oldies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) are good too:

```
var filteredDataTable = dt.Select(@"EmpId > 2
    AND (EmpName <> 'abc' OR EmpName <> 'xyz')
    AND EmpName like '%il%'" );
```

Comment: Pardon my curiosity but what is 'EmpId > 2' for?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov It's just a few examples of the syntax. The 'like' wasn't asked for either.

Answer (score 16):

something like this ? :

```
DataTable dt = ...
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "(EmpName != 'abc' or EmpName != 'xyz') and (EmpID = 5)"
```

Is it what you are searching for?