# Find Distinct from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, distinct

I have a DataTable and in that Table I have 2 Columns Task_Name and Hours.

```
Task_Name   Hours
-----------------
Proj1        2
Proj2        3
Proj1        3
Proj1        2
Proj2        5
```

Now what I finally want is I want a DataTable which will result in:-

```
Task_Name    Hours
------------------
Proj1         7(addition of hours related to Proj1) 
Proj2         8(addition of hours related to Proj2)
```

I Hope I am Clear with my question..
How can I do that..??

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx). Calculate aggregated hours for tasks:

```
var query = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
            group r by r.Field<string>("Task_Name") into g
            select new {
               Task_Name = g.Key,
               Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Hours"))
            };
```

And use this [CopyToDataTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) extension to create new DataTable from anonymous types (if you really need DataTable):

```
var result = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Why do you have to do `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @CédricBignon I believe `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, so you need to call this extension to use LINQ to DataSet methods

Comment: var result = query.CopyToDataTable(); is not working in my case..Error-Error 2 The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: @Farzi that's why I added link to which CopyToDataTable method you will need :) Default implementation works only for types which are DataRow, but this MSDN article has implementation of creating datatable from any type. Just copy-paste code from article into your application

Comment: @lazyberezovsky-Thanx it worked but I want to know one more thing how to avoid null values if value of hours is null coming from database. What change do I need to make to avoid null in hours

Comment: @Farzi you can add `where !r.IsNull("Hours")` just before groupping

Comment: Thankx and how to check if TaskName is not empty..??