# linq with dataTable in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am using datatable on which I want to use Linq. but as i am new to linq i dont know how it uses.
I google it I got lots of information which is not sufficient like. If I am using datatable and i got info like :

```
DataRow r = from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].AsEnumerable()

where dr.Field<Guid>("customerid").ToString() = row[2].ToString()

select dr;    

dt.ImportRow(r);
```

and I have lots of queries like what is "dr".
dr.fields?,
".AsEnumerable()" is not present at my side.

Even this code also doesnt work:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> r = from dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].Select().Where(x => x.Field<Guid>("customerid").ToString() == row[2].ToString())
                        select dr;
```

So can anyone please give me link on which i got all information from beggining on linq.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: have you including System.Linq in your class?

Comment: You need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and make sure you have a `using System.Data;` directive in your file.

Comment: yes i have added System.Linq 
And i tried using DataSet but it doesnt work at all

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Comment: .AsEnumerable() and myRow.Field is not appearing at my end.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate rows to achive it

```
var r = ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Where(r => r["fieldName"].ToString() == "Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

LINQ to DataSet

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

Comment: As per this link it is not working at my end means DataTable.AsEnumerable() is not appearing at my end(Framework 3.5)
What is exact issue?

Comment: Check this 3.5 version http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's like a SQL select query, where dr is the * (that is, it is the returned data).

Some nice examples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b