# How I can filter a dataTable with Linq to datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

hi how i can filter a datatable with linq to datatable? 
I have a DropDownList and there I can select the value of the Modul Column. Now I want to filter the DataTable with this Modul Column.

here is my datatable structure:

```
User | Host | TimeDiff | License | Telefon | Modul
```

Here the Code:

```
protected void drp_Modules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = drp_Modules.SelectedValue;

    DataTable tb = (DataTable)Session["dt_Users"];

    tb = from item in tb //?????

    LoadUsertable(tb);
}
```

Comment: please refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073.aspx

Comment: Is it important to use LINQ ?

Comment: You can use the Select() method on the DataTable

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable) for query DataTable with Linq

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are better of using [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method, but if you have to use LINQ then you can try:

```
DataTable selectedTable = tb.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Modul") == value)
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

This would create a new `DataTable` based on filtered values.

If you use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

```
string expression = "Modul =" + value;
DataRow[] selectedRows = tb.Select(expression);
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party for this one, but thanks, that helped quite a bit with something I'm working on.

Comment: @Habib, Just a simple comment. THANKS!!! I was breaking my head trying to cast the Rows, etc, etc, etc, when I found your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507109/how-to-filter-on-multiple-columns-using-linq I have multiple columns or single column. How can I do either? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use condition to check rows exist in addition before casting. 
System.Linq namespace is required for Any() to work

```
var rows = values.AsEnumerable().Where
            (row => row.Field<string>("Status") == action);//get the rows where the status is equal to action

if(rows.Any())
{
    DataTable dt = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();//Copying the rows into the DataTable as DataRow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To Retrieve the DataTable based on filtering the list of item.**(i.e.,if any of the list item is present in datatable, that matched result will received.

```
 List<string>item=new List<string>(){"TG1","TG2"};     
 DataTable tbsplit = (from a in tbl.AsEnumerable()
              where item.Any(x => a.Field<string>("CSubset").ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper()))
              select a).CopyToDataTable();//By Executing this, the Filter DataTable is obtained
```