# How to Filter Datatable with multiple column values using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I am having 5 controls on my web page like `txtFirstName`(TextBox), `txtDisplayName`(TextBox), `txtFromDate` (TextBox), `txtToDate`(TextBox) and `btnFilter`(button). Also I am binding some data on GridView same page by using DataTable.

Now I want to filter the DataTable by using these search parameters controls which I have mentioned in the above.

Filter Condition is,

- We are not sure about the filled controls and empty controls. So based on the input entered on the controls we need to filter the DataTable.If the control values are empty we should not allow them to filter Datatable.
- We need to filter the data values by LIKE operator or String.Startswith()
- If txtFromDate and txtToDate have filled then we need to filter the data values between the range.
- If all controls are filled then we need to filter the datatable based on all filter parameters wit the date range.

How do we achieve this filtering? Please help me to implement this successfully.
Can we do this by LINQ or Lamda expression? If so, tell me the suggestions.

I have tried two ways but its not working ,

**First way:**

```
var test=dtActions.AsEnumerable().Where(z=>
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text)? z.Field<string>("FirstName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.ToUpper()) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text)?z.Field<string>("DisplayName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtDisplayName.Text.ToUpper()) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCreatedBy.Text)?z.Field<string>("CreatedBy").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtCreatedBy.Text.ToUpper());
```

I dont have idea to get the data between the DateTime textboxes.

**Second way:**

```
var results = from dataRow in dtActions.AsEnumerable()
    where dataRow.Field<string>("FirstName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.ToUpper()) ||
        dataRow.Field<string>("DisplayName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.ToUpper()) ||  
        ((dataRow.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate")>= Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text)) && (dataRow.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate")<= Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text)))
    select dataRow;
```

Comment: please post the code of what you have tried.  That way, we can check it for mistakes, and offer alternate solutions

Comment: Use something like   `dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x=> x["id" ==1).ToList()`

Comment: @kostasch. We need to check textbox is empty or not and will filter the datatable. That too with multiple textbox control values.

Comment: Rather than filtering after getting the data, why not filter it using the parameters being passed into the stored procedure?  I.E. where param = null or myfield = param.

Comment: Check with `dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x=> (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSkata) ? x.description.Contains(txtSkata.Trim()) : "0" == "0")).ToList()`

Comment: @KevinCook: How can we do this by SQL procedure itself? Any Suggestion?

Comment: Linq answer found here: [How I can filter a dataTable with Linq to datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19449449/1316573)

Comment: each filter control data would be passed as a sqlparameter to the stored procedure (or null if the control is empty) and then in the where clause you would check whether the parameter was null or the column data matched the filter data.

Comment: Can you send me the procedure code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code works :

```
var test = dtActions.AsEnumerable().Where(z =>
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) ? true : z.Field<string>("FirstName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.ToUpper())) &&
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text) ? true : z.Field<string>("DisplayName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtDisplayName.Text.ToUpper())) &&
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCreatedBy.Text) ? true : z.Field<string>("CreatedBy").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtCreatedBy.Text.ToUpper()))
);
```

Your Second Query

```
var results = from dataRow in dtActions.AsEnumerable()
        where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) ? true : dataRow.Field<string>("FirstName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.ToUpper())) ||
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text) ? true : dataRow.Field<string>("DisplayName").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtDisplayName.Text.ToUpper())) ||
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCreatedBy.Text) ? true : dataRow.Field<string>("CreatedBy").ToUpper().StartsWith(txtCreatedBy.Text.ToUpper())) ||
            (dataRow.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate") >= Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text) && (dataRow.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate") <= Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text)))
        select dataRow;
```

The reason your code is not working is incorrect conditional operator. If string is null or empty then we return true else we check the field value.

Apply `ToList()` if you want a List in end or `ToArray()` if you want it as an array.

Comment: How to convert it back to datatable again

Answer (score 1):

did you check dataview filters?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx