# How to use Linq for multi-column

Tags: c#, linq

```
if (i == 1) //if dropdown #1 index > 0
{
    strSelectedType = ViewState["EN"].ToString();
    strSelectedCol = "Name";
}
if (i == 2) //if dropdown #2 index > 0
{
    strSelectedType = ViewState["SU"].ToString();
    strSelectedCol = "Super";
}
if (i == 3) //if dropdown #3 index > 0
{
    strSelectedType = ViewState["DT"].ToString();
    strSelectedCol = "Deran";
}
if (i == 4) //if dropdown #4 index > 0
{
    strSelectedType = ViewState["PR"].ToString();
    strSelectedCol = "PRate";
}
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest = (DataTable)ViewState["gvDataTable"];

DataTable selectedTable = dtTest.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == strSelectedType)
              .CopyToDataTable();
```

The above code is only using one column to filter.

How can I modify the `dtText.AsEnumerable()` so that it will filter like this:

```
DataTable selectedTable = dtTest.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(if (dropdown #1 > 0) {r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == strSelectedType }
                if (dropdown #2 > 0) { r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == strSelectedType }
                if (dropdown #3 > 0) { r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == strSelectedType }
                if (dropdown #4 > 0) { r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == strSelectedType })
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

It will iterate through each dropdown append filter if the selected index > 0.

Comment: In your code `i` cannot be equal to two different values at same time. What is condition for filtering by several columns?

Comment: The first code section is when I was selecting one column to filter. I would like to change it so it can use one or more columns to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up query step by step. Just conditionally add new filters and assign result to original query variable:

```
var query = dtTest.AsEnumerable();

if (dropdown1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == ViewState["EN"].ToString());

if (dropdown2.SelectedIndex > 0)
    query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Super") == ViewState["SU"].ToString());

// etc

DataTable selectedTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

If you can change ViewState keys so that they'll match dropdowns ids (or vise versa), then you can easily build a list of filters and then apply them all in a loop:

```
var columns = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    ["EN"] = "Name",
    ["SU"] = "Super",
    ["DT"] = "Deran",
    ["PR"] = "PRate"
};

var filters = from ddl in Controls.OfType<DropDownList>()
              where ddl.SelectedIndex > 0 && columns.ContainsKey(ddl.ID)
              select new {
                  Column = columns[ddl.ID], 
                  Value = ViewState[ddl.ID].ToString()
              };

var query = dtTest.AsEnumerable();
foreach(var fitler in filters)
   query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>(fitler.Column) == fitler.Value);

DataTable selectedTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Since we are only using `=`, what if more than one dropdownlist has a index of > 0?

Comment: @SiKni8 it's not clear how you are using dropdownlists. In your question there is some pseudo-code for checking this conditions. Also as you can see I use different dropdowns to build query

Comment: The first code section in my question was only for one column filtering. In your code for example, you are using `query = ` and then `query = `. Doesn't the second `query=` overwrite the first one?

Comment: @SiKni8 second query overwrites what is stored in `query`. But you are missing that second query is *modified* first query: `query = Something(query)`. Thus you are keep modifying original query and storing last modifications in original variable

Comment: @SiKni8 no problem) How do you put values into ViewState? I think your code can be simplified more if you'll explain how ViewState values related to your dropboxes

Comment: I am using ViewState to keep the selected values so when the page does postback it remembers the selection. It's a SharePoint webpart so it was losing the selected value.

Comment: @SiKni8 can you change ViewState keys so the they'll match dropdowns ids?

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

There are some simplications can be made for your case, for instance prepare this first:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() {"EN", "SU", "DT", "PR"};
List<string> b = new List<string>() {"Name", "Super", "Deran", "PRate"};
```

Then you could simply do:

```
strSelectedType = ViewState[a[i-1]].ToString();
strSelectedCol = b[i-1];
```

Then if you have list of dropdown, you could also do

```
var query = dtTest.AsEnumerable();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  if (dropdown #i-1 index > 0) {
    query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>(strSelectedCol) == ViewState[strSelectedType].ToString());
    var result = query.CopyToDataTable();
    //Do something, your DataTable is here
  }
```

You could use `List<KeyValuePair>` too:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> lkvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(){
    new KeyValuePair("EN", "Name"),
    new KeyValuePair("SU", "Super"),
    new KeyValuePair("DT", "Deran"),
    new KeyValuePair("PR", "PRate")
}
```

And use it like this

```
strSelectedType = ViewState[lkvp[i-1].Key].ToString();
strSelectedCol = lkvp[i-1].Value;
```

Comment: Thumb up, but maybe change two list declaring to one DIctionary?

Comment: @progpow ah yes! that is certainly an alternative since we only need to you key and value

Comment: sorry to Tuple :) We also use third type for Index Tuple<int,string,string>

Comment: @progpow the index is still needed. List of KVP or Tuple may also be an option.

Comment: Will this work, if there are more than one dropdownlist selected > 0?

Comment: @SiKni8 I do not put `break;` in the `for loop`, so naturally it goes through all. The only thing is, I am not sure about `CopyToDataTable`. If it does what it suppose to, then it should be okay.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary from the get-go? Using a KVP in a list of your own is `not intuitive`.

Comment: I have to use another for loop to save the strSelectedType and strSelectedCol?

Comment: "to save the strSelectedType and strSelectedCol" sorry, I don't get this? you want to save strSelectedType and strSelectedCol? And there is another loop? Both are local `string`, no? At least I infer it so from their names

Comment: Sorry let me be clear, how will the loop know to go through each strSelectedType/strSelectedCol to match what is in the viewstate?

Comment: I am sorry `strSelectedType = ViewState[lkvp[i-1].Key].ToString();
strSelectedCol = lkvp[i-1].Value;` will let us know to go through each... makes sense now :)

Comment: @SiKni8 sorry, it seems like the fault could be mine for not understanding your question. At first, because I see your `if (i == 1)` `if(i == 2)` etc, I thought that you may only have one `i` value at a time, but if you need the `strSelectedType/strSelectedCol` to be dynamically changed, then you could put them in the for loop too. However, I cannot infer much from the question what is the exact case. A more info would be helpful

Comment: @SiKni8 ow, great! So did it get into you? :) anyway, you could always put those two in the `for` loop if you need them to be evaluated for all dropdown list...

Comment: `strSelectedType = ViewState[lkvp[i-1].Key].ToString();` is saying which KVP to use during the loop... took me a while but i get it now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a predicate builder.

It helps especially when you don't know the exact options to filter. You simple build your predicate before you get to the point of filtering.

it improves performs of you application because you won't need to filter your collection more than once.

Read the link below:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: PredicateBuilder for simple filtering? Overkill

Comment: One word says it all: overkill.

Comment: Its best you explain how it is overkill to let us know.

Comment: @ZiregbeOtee add some real code and you'll see. Currently it's link-only answer

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Question for you, since you are using only `=` how will it use for more than one dropdownlist? You aren't using `+=`

Comment: @SiKni8 sorry, I don't get you. Where `+=` should be used? I can't find such place in code

Answer (score 1):

`Where` calls can be chained:

```
var rows = dtTest.AsEnumerable();

if (...)
    rows = rows.Where(r => ...);

if (...)
    rows = rows.Where(r => ...);

...

var result = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to store the conditions for later use, you can do that as well:

```
var conditions = new List<Func<DataRow, bool>>();

if (...)
    conditions.Add(r => ...);

if (...)
    conditions.Add(r => ...);

...

var query = dtTest.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var cond in conditions)
    query = query.Where(cond);

var result = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Although it is using `row = ...` if more than one ddl i selected it will use for all?

Comment: @SiKni8: I am sorry, I don't understand your question.