# C# Two Excel File inner join

Tags: c#

I would like to ask if it is possible to retrieve a row of data from a INNER JOIN query from TWO different Excel files (example. excel1.xls, excel2.xls).
I am using C# .net. and an `OledbConnection`.

Excel1.xls
Column 1
**BookID**
1234
1515
2315

Excel2.xls
Column 1
**BookID**
1234
1515
1100
1412
2215

Goal:
I must retrieve only those rows in Excel1.xls that are included in Excel2.xls

Here's my code for the function:
**txtshowstopperpath.text = path of the Excel1.xls**
**txtexcelpath.text = Path of the Excel2.xls**

```
    sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={1};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    oConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnString);
oConn.Open();
sCommand = "SELECT * FROM [" + txtshowstopperpath.Text + "].[Sheet1$] A INNER JOIN [" + txtexcelpath.Text + "].[Sheet1$] B on A.[Book ID] = B.[Book ID]";       
oComm = new OleDbCommand(sCommand, oConn);
oRdr = oComm.ExecuteReader();
oTbl = new DataTable();
oTbl.Load(oRdr);
foreach (DataRow row in oTbl.Rows)
     {
         dgridshowrep.DataSource = oTbl;
    }
oConn.Close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: correction: rows of Data

Comment: Show examples of your data and format your code as code.

Comment: @RobAnthony - edited my post. sorry as this is my first time posting in this site. thank you

Comment: No, I don't believe you can. You will probably need to create two different data tables and the compare the data using some other method.

Comment: @MarkKram - thanks for your reply. Im stuck with this function.

Comment: I would look at using LINQ to extract the data that you want, this will get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449449/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable-with-linq-to-datatable

Comment: Here is a better link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp