# Datasource not reflecting sorting in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I am binding a `DataTable` as the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`. I enabled the `SortMode` property to `Automatic` for all `DataGridViewColumn`. But when I am sorting on DataGridView the Sort change is not being reflected in the underlying DataSource which is the DataTable.

For example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("Alex", 27);
table.Rows.Add("Jack", 65);
table.Rows.Add("Bill", 22);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Now if I was to get the selected row like below it will always return the row at 0 Index in the DataTable **even after sorting** which is `Alex, 27`.

```
DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
newRow.ItemArray = table.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0])].ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
```

Can someone please suggest how I should go about this situation?

Comment: Sorting is just happening in the UI. Why would you want to sort your underlying datasource?
Your datasource just holds yuor data, if you want to access it in a certain order, yuo can use indexes or views for that, certainly not anything an end user decides might be fun to sort on.

Comment: why should sort reflect in data table when you are sorting Gridview ?

Comment: You can sort the datasource in the code behind.

Comment: Kindly, show some code specially your query before datatable was bind to your DataGridView.

Comment: If you have the option I would really recommend WPF, it's much better at this sort of thing.

Comment: @tariq How do I sort it from code behind.Some examples would help. @Edper A simple `SELECT` query that brings all columns of a single table and fills the `DataTable`. Why is that important again? @JMK I would if I could.But not my choice. Any suggestions please!

Comment: @Md.lbrahim , There are many ways of sorting in the code behind, This will require you to provide all the relevant code along with the explanation of required functionality. :)

Comment: @tariq I have updated my question.Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim , if i am correct do you want this-- that when you sort your grid in User Interface the sorted order should reflect in your underlying datasource i.e datatable in your case ?

Comment: @tariq Yes. I exactly want this and this should have been default.

Comment: oh God ! i thought web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all the `DataTable` object is detached from `DataGridView` even if you bind it to `DataSource`, that is, if you change your `DataGridView` it will not affect your `DataTable`. And in your case you want the sorting in `DataGridView` to be reflected in `DataTable`. And so for that reason you need to catch an event every time there is changes in ordering/sorting in `DataGridView`. You need to catch therefore for that regard the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event of the `DataGridView`.

Another important thing is, in achieving a synchronize sorting of both `DataTable` and `DataGridView` is the `DefaultView` method of `Datable` class that has the `Sort` property. So, what we are going to do is every time the `DataGridView` is changed sorting-wise we will sort the `DataTable` also.

First of all we need to make a DataTable object global so that we could access it anywhere later on.

```
DataTable table;
```

Secondly, we need to initialize an event listener for `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` and for our practical purpose we will set it at `Form` constructor.

```
InitializeComponent();
dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
```

We then have this empty Mouse event handler:

```
 void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {            

 }
```

And if the above method doesn't automatically come out, just copy and paste in your code.

And for the sake of illustration we will add the `DataTable` during the `Form Load` and in this case I am going to use your own code:

```
table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("Alex", 27);
table.Rows.Add("Jack", 65);
table.Rows.Add("Bill", 22);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

And then finally we will put some code in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event:

```
  void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
  {            
      if (dataGridView1.SortOrder.ToString() == "Descending") // Check if sorting is Descending
      {
          table.DefaultView.Sort = dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name + " DESC"; // Get Sorted Column name and sort it in Descending order
      }
      else
      {
        table.DefaultView.Sort = dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name + " ASC";  // Otherwise sort it in Ascending order
      }
      table = table.DefaultView.ToTable(); // The Sorted View converted to DataTable and then assigned to table object.
  }
```

You could now use table object and sorted according to the sorting order of the `DataGridView`.

Just to confirm my claim, we will make a button in your form named `button1` and when clicked it will show the first row and the sorted column value, like:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    String sortedValue = dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name == "Name" : table.Rows[0][0].ToString() ? table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
     MessageBox.Show(sortedValue);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your `DataTable` into `BindingSource` container and set this class to data source of `DataGridView`.

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
// another grid view options...
```

To learn about `BindingSort`, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx).

Comment: So, just wrapping my `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` enables sorting from `DataGridView` to the `DataTable`? What is `BindingSort` btw?

Comment: I did like you said. Still no automatic sorting on the datatable.

Comment: yes, but if you change the `DataGridView` sort order, the `BindingSource` reflect this change...

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but still no easy solution mentioned, so I post it here for the people looking for the answer nowadays:

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).Row;
int index = yourDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

`index` will be the index of the row in your DataTable corresponding with the selected row in DataGridView, however you have sorted it.

Answer (score 2):

For others coming here for same reason as I.

I couldn't get the underlying data sorted either, thus when I was deleting a row, it was deleting the wrong one.

I found `DataTable` will not be sorted but only `DataTable.DefaultView` will be.

So instead of `DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[0];`

You would do `DataRow row = dataTable.DefaultView[0].Row;`

Answer (score 0):

I found another alternative solution where I get value of a unique column from my `DataGridView` and then query the underlying DataSource the `DataTable` to get the rows even though the `DataTable` is not sorted.

But I'd like to know how to sort the `DataTable` though.
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593/1565402)

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim check my answer above.