# Sorting DataTable Column Using DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to sort a `DataTable` that contains some dates and values. I pass the `DataTable` information to a `DataGridView` and sort the data, then try to pass it back.

The below code runs successfully, but does not produce any difference:

```
Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ChartTable
Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(Form1.DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
ChartTable = CType(Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Copy()
ChartTable = ChartTable.DefaultView.ToTable

For i = 0 To ChartTable.Rows.Count - 1
    Debug.Print("ChartTable = " & ChartTable.Rows(i)(0) & ", DataGrid = " & Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
Next
```

Here's the Output from the `Debug.Print`

```
ChartTable = 30/12/15, DataGrid = 27/10/15
ChartTable = 27/10/15, DataGrid = 19/11/15
ChartTable = 29/12/15, DataGrid = 22/12/15
ChartTable = 22/12/15, DataGrid = 29/12/15
ChartTable = 19/11/15, DataGrid = 30/12/15
```

The `ChartTable` (which is the DataTable) is still in it's original un-sorted state.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You want to sort datas in the query or allow the user to sort the DataGridView?

Comment: The user can't see the `DataGridView`, it's only being used to try and provide sorting

Comment: Does it sort your datagridview if you create a button with `DataGridView1.Sort(Form1.DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)` ?

Comment: Yes, the Output from the `Debug.Print` shows that the datagridview has been sorted in ascending order

Comment: Quote : "First of all the DataTable object is detached from DataGridView even if you bind it to DataSource, that is, if you change your DataGridView it will not affect your DataTable."


Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681947/datasource-not-reflecting-sorting-in-datagridview), for full answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's because Datagridview sorts the data for himself, not doing changes to his datasource. When you copy the datasource, are copying the non-sorted datatable.

To do what you want, i think you may have to do a process to get row by row of the datagridview to the datatable.

But, in my opinion, it should be a lot better (and faster) if you sort the info before to fill the datatable.

Comment: I can't sort the info before because it is read line by line from a word document that unfortunetly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to sort your data table:

```
    Dim filterExp As String = ""
    Dim sortExp As String = dt.Columns.Item(0).ColumnName
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dtrow() As DataRow
    dtrow = dt.Select(filterExp, sortExp, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

    For i = 0 To dtrow.Length - 1
       DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dtrow(i)(dt.Columns.Item(0).ColumnName))
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.`. So I tried removing the Datasource, but the columns are removed and I get an error that you can't add rows if there are no columns present

Comment: After removing the datagridview data source doing this Datagridview1.Datasource=Nothing, you have to add a column like this: Dim workCol As DataColumn = datatable.Columns.Add( _
    "Column1", Type.GetType("System.Datetime"))

Comment: You have to add that code below the for loop. Let me now if it works.