# take top 10 or 20 rows from dynamic datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 100 records in my Datable says to be in

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
```

`dt` have `100` of records say column name as `sub_id(contain int datatype)` and `subheadername(contain nvarchar(150))` , I want top `20 records` from this `dt` in `ascending` order

I am putting code as

```
//dtlcategories.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20).ToList();
dtlcategories.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20).ToList();
dtlcategories.DataBind();
```

Here dtlcategories is Datalist but on running error is coming as 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'subheadername'.

**ANSWER IS SOLVED**

```
dtlcategories.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20).copytodatatable();
dtlcategories.DataBind();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a couple different ways you can do this using LINQ. These will both return the same results.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20);

dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20);
```

If you're going to use the result as the source of data for another control, you may need to call `.ToList()` after `.Take(x)`.

*Edit:*

I changed the column name based on your edit. If you want to sort by id instead (you didn't specify), just replace "subheadername" with "sub_id".

Comment: Please see my edited question and edit your answer as per my column name and in orderby ascending

Comment: how should i take this value in my datalist.datasource??

Comment: i am putting like ...  dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20).ToList();

           

            dtlcategories.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["subheadername"]).Take(20).ToList();....butt error is coming as  'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'subheadername'.

Comment: i have edited my question, please made me know whats my mistake??

Comment: If i used to put sub_id than error as "System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'sub_id "

Answer (score 2):

This query fetches top 20 records from db and then orders them by the `sub_id` column.

```
var topTwenty = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(20).OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("sub_id"));
```

Comment: @GrantWinney That's the way I understand the question, though.

Comment: Please see my edited question and edit your answer as per my column name and in orderby ascending

Comment: if i want to order this on subheadername than i used to take nvarchar(150) in place of int???

Comment: @Xtremcool no, C# does not recognize `nvarchar(150)` as a type, you have to use `string` instead

Comment: i am getting error "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."...when i used to fill this record in my datalist tool like   dtlcategories.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(20).OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("sub_id"));
            dtlcategories.DataBind();

Comment: try appending `.Cast<DataRow>()` as in the Grant Winney's answer

Comment: i have edited my question, please made me know whats my mistake??

Comment: you have "sibheadername" instead of "subheadername"

Answer (score 1):

```
dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => row["sub_id"]).Take(20);
```

This will return you IEnumerable. Now iterate through the IEnumerable and add them to another data table. Now your final data table is ready!!

Comment: Please see my edited question and edit ypur answer as per my column name

Answer (score 1):

this code orders data according to date and takes first 100 row.

```
 var table = new DataTable();
 var t = table.AsEnumerable();
 var result = t.OrderByDescending(f => f.Field<DateTime>(new DataColumn("Date"))).Take(100);
```

Update:

```
var table = new DataTable();
var t = table.AsEnumerable();
var result = t.OrderBy(f => f.Field<String>(new DataColumn("subheadername"))).Take(20)
```

Comment: Please see my edited question and edit your answer as per my column name and in orderby ascending

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("sub_id< 100 ");
```

Comment: Please see my edited question and edit ypur answer as per my column name