# Delete a data table from data set in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

In c#,i want to delete a datatable from dataset,if all the values of the datatable are zero.

How to achieve above functionality

I am using this code to add values into datatable

```
for (int row = startRowParcel + 1; row <= endRowParcel; row++) {
    List<string> rateRow = new List<string>();

    for (int col = startColumnNsa; col <= endColumnNsa; col++) {
        if (Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value) == null)
            rateRow.Add("0");
        else if (Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value) == "1/2")
            rateRow.Add("0.5");
        else
            rateRow.Add(Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value));
    }

    tbPriority.Rows.Add(rateRow.ToArray());
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of deleting if all are zero why not check your list for values other than 0 and if true then add to your Datatable else dont?

Comment: The values are strings which are not convertible to `int`, so what means `zero` in this case?

Comment: @Sindhujampani Look at the answer by TYY similar to my answer looks like the one that will be helpful for you

Comment: if((rateRow.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x != "0")))    {                                                                 tbPmServices.Rows.Add(rateRow.ToArray()); 
                                }Actually i tried this.but it is adding the row even the entire row has "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can achieve this by using below code:**

```
     for(int i=0;i<dt.rows.count;i++)
    {
          for(intj=0;j<=dt.columns.count;j++)
            {

             if( dt.rows[i][j]!=0)
            {
                 flag=1;
                 break;
              }

             }
    }

    if(flag==1)
    {
       // dont remove the table
    }

    else
    {

     ds.tables.remove(dt);
    }

}
```

Iterate through that datatable ,check for non zero values, if all are zero remove it else not

Hope this helps..

Comment: cannot apply indexing to an expression of type "System.Data.DataTable".This errow was coming at the position of i in if( dt[i][j]!=0)

Comment: @sindhu..sorry for the mistake...edited the code..can you please try now.?

Comment: if( dt.rows[i].columns[j]!=0) showing error at columns, as it doesnt have an extension columns

Comment: Sindu..can you please check now..i have updated the syntax inside if condidtion..

Comment: if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]) == "0") it is working like this.anyways thankyou soo much...my requirement was fulfilled

Answer (score 1):

This LINQ approach finds all tables where all rows' fields are `"0"`:

```
var allZeroTables = dsPriorities.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
    .Where(tbl => tbl.AsEnumerable()
        .All(r => tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .All(c => r.Field<string>(c) == "0")));
foreach (DataTable zeroTable in allZeroTables.ToList())
    dsPriorities.Tables.Remove(zeroTable);
```

[`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a short circuiting method that stops on the first non-match.

Note that the `ToList()` is required since you cannot modify the `DataSet`'s `DataTableCollection` from within the `foreach` without creating a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Field<double>("nameOfColumn") != 0)) {
    //delete data table
}
```

For more information see [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Comment: Instead of `!..Any(.. != 0)`, you could simply use `All(.. == 0)`

Comment: I used to use that before but found out it's much slower than a for...loop with an exit on first invalid result. But on small DataTable this performance hit shouldn't be too much visible.

Comment: `All()` will iterate, always, all the collection. `Any()` iterates only until the first occurrence. Yes, it's more obscure syntax, but in a large collection, `Any` will do better performance

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = startRowParcel + 1; row <= endRowParcel; row++) {
    List<string> rateRow = new List<string>();

    for (int col = startColumnNsa; col <= endColumnNsa; col++) {
        if (Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value) == null)
            rateRow.Add("0");
        else if (Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value) == "1/2")
            rateRow.Add("0.5");
        else
            rateRow.Add(Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value));
    }

    if (rateRow.Any(x=> x != "0"))
    tbPriority.Rows.Add(rateRow.ToArray());
} 
//Then you can check if tbPriority has any rows if it doesn't then remove it from the dataset
if (!tbPriority.Rows.Any())
    // delete dataTable
```

if rateRow contains any value other than "0" the rows will get added.

Comment: actually if an entire row contains "0" and other row doesnot contains "0",then i want those rows to add to the datatable. @TYY

Comment: if (rateRow.Any(x=> x != "0")) this was adding the row even the entire row has zeros. @TYY