# How to get data from datacolumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am doing an foreach on all columns on my DataTables row. I want to get data from a specific column but cant figure out how to do it. See code.

```
DataTable dt = mHandler.GetRegistrtationProgress(customer);
int column = 1;
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    string hutt = dc.ToString();
    if (column == 11)
    {
        if (hutt.Equals("1"))
        {
            addSpecificPicture();   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (hutt.Equals("1"))
        {
            addPicture(column);
        }
    }
    column++;
}
```

When i run this code I only get name on column but there must be a good method to get value? Or not?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Get values from the first column and call `addPictures` on each value ?

Comment: Nope! :) I have one row in my DataTable and I want to go through each column in that row, get the value from that column and depending on the value add a picture.

Comment: Then you should get that row and then run a foreach over its items, not the columns. The columns are NOT the cells ...

Comment: Ok, thought it was possible to run on the columns... will try that...

Comment: You'd have to loop through DataRows for parsing, instead of DataColumns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to retrieve the value of your only one row for every column then you have to use the dc.ColumnName property

```
DataTable dt = mHandler.GetRegistrtationProgress(customer);
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
     string hutt = dt.Rows[0][dc.ColumnName].ToString();
     ....
```

Of course you could simply loop over the column of the row using an indexer

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
     string hutt = row[i].ToString();
```

There is also the option of the property ItemArray in the DataRow object where every element of the array contains the corresponding value

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
for(int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
{
     string hutt = row.ItemArray[i].ToString();
     ....
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i tried to achive, get value from one single row. I used your first code sample and it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through the rows first, then columns.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
        string hutt = dr[dc].ToString()
    }
}
```

Or like Steve answered, if you have only 1 row.

You also can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593/2532582)