# Get Filled row count in data table C#

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable

I have a data table 'dt_ExcelData' with in my program. I need to get how many rows in that data table. I'm using this to get the row count.

dt_ExcelData.Rows.Count

But in my data table , some times there is blank rows in end of the data table. I don't need to get blank rows for the row count.

How can I get that?

I'm using C# windows application form.

Comment: Add a where clause and exclude unwanted rows

Comment: How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable