# C# Datatable How to Group Like Rows

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am still relatively new to C# and I was wondering if there is a built-in function to do the following:

-I am loading rows from a database into a **DataGridView via a DataTable**

-I have many rows with the same value in one column but a differing value in antoher column, EG:

```
NAME, PRICE
chair, 7.00
chair, 6.00
chair, 8.00
table, 15.00
table, 17.00
plate, 4.00
plate, 4.50
```

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to loop through each row, and take the cheapest price for each product and send it to another List/Object?

I have only started using DataTables and DataGridView elements today so I am a little uncertain the best way to proceed.  Basically I want an end list containing one of each product with the cheapest price found next to it.  EG

```
NAME, PRICE
chair, 6.00
table, 15.00
plate, 4.00
```

I am not sure if using an Object, List or Dictionary would be the best in this situation and was wondering if someone can shed some more light please.  :)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that you `datatable` looks like this:

```
var dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("NAME",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("PRICE",typeof(float));

dt.Rows.Add("chair", 7.00);
dt.Rows.Add("chair", 6.00);
dt.Rows.Add("chair", 8.00);
dt.Rows.Add("table", 15.00);
dt.Rows.Add("table", 17.00);
dt.Rows.Add("plate", 4.00);
dt.Rows.Add("plate", 4.50);
```

And you have an object that you want to present the information in like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public float Price {get;set;}
}
```

The you can do a linq query like this to get the min price and the name:

```
var result= (
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("NAME") into g
    select new Foo
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Price=g.Min (x =>x.Field<float>("PRICE"))
    }
).ToList();
```

This will get the following result:

```
chair 6 
table 15 
plate 4
```

Reference:

- [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)
- [How to: Group Query Results (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)
- [Find the Minimum Value in a Numeric Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386980(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!  I need to investigate LINQ more as this is a far more efficient and simple solution compared to what I was intending to do.  If I wanted to add more properties to the Foo Class and save them via the LINQ query can you advise how I would do that?

Comment: @AaronMcKelvie : No problem. I updated the answer with some resources for you to read up on

Comment: Thanks again Arion, You've been very helpful I'll check out those links!  I was wondering if you had any advice on the above comment edit I made?