# how to get a DataRow object from a datatable using Select function on an array in C#

Tags: c#, select, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to use the select function filtered by a list as oposed to a value

if `dt_old` is a datatable, `CFKEY` is a column of `dt_old`, this statement uses Select for a specific Value and it work fine.

```
DataRow[] dt_oldDuplicateRow = dt_old.Select("CFKEY = '1'");
```

I can't find a way to use select to filter on an array or list based on an other datatable, I would like to do something like this.

```
DataColumn dc = dt_new.Columns["CFKEY"];
DataRow[] dt_oldDuplicateRow = dt_old.Select("CFKEY in " + dc );
```

where `dt_new` is the same format as `st_old`. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the list of keys are your choice or a list obtained from `dt_new`. Anyway,

```
List<string> listOfDuplicateKeys = createTheKeyList();

DataRow[] dt_oldDuplicateRow = dt_old.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Where(dr => listOfDuplicateKeys.Contains(dr["CFKEY"].ToString()))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must refrence to  System.Data.DataSetExtensions  and use AsEnumerable() for datatable

```
var results =  dt_old.AsEnumerable().Select()
```

check this question [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks serdar, it's exactly what I needed.

My list was obtained from dt_new and I slightly changed your code.

```
var list = dt_new.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("CFKEY"))
                                .ToList();

DataRow[] dt_oldDuplicateRow = dt_old.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                .Where(dr => list.Contains(dr["CFKEY"].ToString()))
                                .ToArray();
```