# Linq query not including items contained in list (of class)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble with this Linq query. I have a data table (including a Name column) with all the data I want to process. I want to do a Linq query to this data table, but I want to exclude names also found in myNegativeList where amount >= 15.

myNegativeList has (Name = "John"; Amount = 5) John **should not be excluded** from the Linq Query.
myNegativeList also has (Name = "Sally"; Amount = 100) Sally **should be excluded** from the Linq Query.

```
Class ListItems
    Public Name As String
    Public Amount As Decimal
End Class

Sub GetList()

    'get data table
    Dim NoticeTable As DataTable = GetTable 'has Name and other data

    'get my list of names I don't want
    Dim myNegativeList As List(Of ListItems) = getMyList

    'Psuedo code here 
    Dim Cust = From Notice In NoticeTable _
               Where Notice.Name not in (Select Name from myList where Amount >= 15)

End Sub
```

How do I do a Linq query excluding names (existing in myNegativeList AND amount >= 15)

Comment: try to not use "not" operator in your query

Comment: @SantoshaEpili you should *not* not use the "not" operator in VB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and do it like this:

```
Dim Cust  = From row In NoticeTable.AsEnumerable() _ 
           Let name = row.Field(Of String)("Name") _ 
           Where Not myNegativeList.Where(Function(c) c.Amount >= 15 ) _ 
                                   .Any(Function(c) c.Name = name) _
           Select row
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable) for another example on how to do Linq with DataTable

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
Dim result = From dr In NoticeTable.Rows
                 Where Not myNegativeList.Any(Function(x) x.Amount >= 15 AndAlso x.Name = dr("Name"))
                 Select dr("Name")
```

I am not sure why .Net Fiddle is not supporting DataTable, but you can copy the code i have tried from [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F841NN).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Linq Join is an inner join that would exclude most of my data records from the data table. Only a few appear in the myNegativeList.

Comment: @D_Bester - Yes, I misunderstood your question! I thought you want to filter only those names from dataTable which are present in negative list, Anyways have updated the code. Please check and you can check the sample data I have used in Fiddle.

Comment: This is great! I used `Select dr` instead of `Select dr("Name")` because I actually wanted the entire data row. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I checked out your fiddle and saw the error message asked for a reference to `System.XML`. I added it and the error was gone.

Comment: @D_Bester - Okay Thanks for that! Got confused cz in .Net DataTable is present in `System.Data` namespace.