# creating one datatable from two

Tags: c#

I have two datatables with identical schemas, business partners and addresses. I'm trying to combine them in a specific format in order to import into another system.

Basically, I want the output to be as follows:

- Business Partner
- All associated addresses
- Next business partner
- All associated addresses

Here is the latest code I'm trying:

```
            var finalDt = BpDt.Clone();

            foreach(DataRow BpRow in BpDt.Rows)
            {
                finalDt.ImportRow(BpRow);

                foreach(DataRow AddressRow in AddressDt.Rows)
                {
                    if(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"]).Equals(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"])))
                    finalDt.ImportRow(AddressRow);
                }
            }
```

It seems to get caught in a infinite loop but I don't understand why. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like...

```
if(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"]).Equals(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"])))
```

will always be `true`. So you would just be inserting every `AddressRow` for each `BpRow`. Depending on your dataset size, this could be taking a really long time. Should the `id` comparison be this?

```
if(Convert.ToString(AddressRow["id"]).Equals(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"])))
```

Conceptually this would be similar to a join on the `id` field.

A better approach might be to use LINQ. If you use the `AsEnumerable()` extension for `DataTable` you could query `AddressDt` using LINQ...

[LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Comment: Answered first and correctly and got downvoted. Interesting.

Comment: well i'm an idiot... you are right I'm basically trying to do a join and was comparing the wrong fields...

luckily there are only about 10,000 records so it goes quick but I'll take a look at LINQ for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to everyone from time to time :)

Comment: @temarsden To the Victor go the spoils :-)

Comment: @JimBeam Nice, I see what you did there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to this is terrible. But if you insist on going down this road, this should work:

```
 var finalDt = BpDt.Clone();

            foreach(DataRow BpRow in BpDt.Rows)
            {
                finalDt.ImportRow(BpRow);

                foreach(DataRow AddressRow in AddressDt.Rows)
                {
                    if(Convert.ToString(BpRow["id"]).Equals(Convert.ToString(AddressRow["id"])))
                    finalDt.ImportRow(AddressRow);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...

What would be a better approach?

Comment: @user2486993 How about doing this in the database instead? This is a data issue, not a coding issue, per-se, so why not handle it server side with SQL?

Comment: I agree that it is a silly way of doing it...

I'm not sure how to approach this problem via SQL but i will look into it