# Linq Statement in Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datatable

I'm getting the data of my Datatable into a List but i need to get only the items of a matching date how can i do a Linq statement of my datatable to filter the data on the provided date?
My table Structure is taken from a stored procedure

This is my Code:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("JoinedRecords", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
            myTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            conn.Close();

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myTable.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    var row = myTable.Rows[rowIndex];
  var rowValues = new List<string>(); 
  foreach (DataColumn column in myTable.Columns)//Where column.Date.Day == 3
  {
      rowValues.Add(row[column].ToString());
  }

var jsonRow = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rowValues);

                    // Write current row
                    reader.Write(jsonRow);

                    // Add separating comma
                    if (rowIndex != myTable.Rows.Count - 1)
                        reader.WriteLine(",");
```

}
How can i do this? 
There a data in my datatable that has datetime format

Comment: Can we see the structure of some of the data in the DataTable?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
var myTable = new DataTable();
var rowValues = myTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("Date") == "3").ToList();
```

And use a `.Select()` before the `.ToList()` to get what you want? 
Hard to provide more with an example of the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowValues = new List<String>();
var value = from r in rowValues
            where column.Date.Day == 3
            select r;
```

Comment: im getting erros using your sintax, could it be a LinQ sintax pls?

Comment: Here's a similar example from the MSDN website:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907066.aspx