# How to get the highest value from a datatable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `datatable` which has a few columns. I want to return the one which matches my id, with the highest value in the `verlabel` column, in this case I want to return 1.1

[image: Datatable structure]

How do I achieve this? Current code just returns the column name into my string variable, rather than the actual value.

```
Namespace.EnquiryEngine.DataLists ds2 = new Namespace.EnquiryEngine.DataLists("VERSION");
Namespace.Common.KeyValueCollection ds2params = new Namespace.Common.KeyValueCollection();
ds2params.Add("id", class.ID); 
ds2.ChangeParameters(ds2params);
System.Data.DataTable dt = ds2.Run(false) as System.Data.DataTable;
String version = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["version"]);
```

New code:

```
var highestVersion = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                  where row.Field<int>("id") == doc.ID
                  select row.Field<double>("verlabel")).Max();
```

Comment: Have a look at [linq to datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but probably something along:

```
var highestVersion = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where row.Field<string>("id") == class.ID
                      select row.Field<double>("verlabel")).Max();
```

Comment: This will result in `double` not `DataRow` as expected

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - the expected is actually a string (`String version`) but I decided to keep in on double. He can add `ToString()` if needed :)

Comment: I like the look of this answer - simple and to the point. Unfortunately, I'm getting exceptions about `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<double>` not containing a definition for `max`. Any ideas?

Comment: @jbab8 - are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: @jbab8, also beware of the types used for `id` and `verlabel` columns, since they are based on certain assumptions and may not be totally correct

Comment: @GiladGreen Without that it would fail much earlier than `Max`, it is Linq All through

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - incorrect. I've just removed the `using System.Linq` from my code and got the same compile error that he is receiving. And I got it on the `.Max()`

Comment: I'm using `system.linq` and have amended `id` to be an `int` rather than string. Still getting the missing definition for `max` though! So close!

Comment: @jbab8 - can you edit your question to add the new version of the code? So I can copy it and check?

Comment: @GiladGreen I've added the new version

Comment: @GiladGreen Alright for `DataTable` its different, since its part of an Extension class in `System.Data`, only Linq code is Max in your case and None in my case. Nonetheless +1 from my side, its a good solution.

Comment: @jbab8 - Saw the new version. Sorry to ask more but can you add a print screen showing it.. having the code + the using? because it is strange..

Comment: @GiladGreen Unfortunately not because this is part of an enterprise application, which is closed source. It's against our licence agreement to post any code, even custom stuff, hence me using placeholders like "Namespace" and "class" and removing a lot of other things (none of which affect this bit directly btw). It may be that it's not 100% using LINQ to talk to this data source, which is why even after importing the assembly / reference it still doesn't like it. I may contact the company for an alternative method!

Comment: @jbab8 - I'm pretty sure that answer will be no but worth checking - do any other linq methods give you the problem? and do you have the problem with `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Here `AsEnumerable()` belongs to `System.Data.DataTableExtensions`, No Linq

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - I know and that is what I want him to check :) from what I see the only using my snippet needs is `linq` and `data`.

Comment: I had problems with `AsEnumerable` until I imported the `System.Data.DataTableExtensions` assembly! I'm having problems with other examples posted, things like `FirstOrDefault()` are missing as well.

Comment: Yes as @GiladGreen suggested you are surely missing `System.Linq`, check both assembly and namespace import

Comment: @jbab8 - I'm not sure.. maybe something stupid like resetting VS... I'm just guessing now haha

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Thanks :)

Comment: @GiladGreen I have kinda given up now. I've no doubt your solution (and yours, Mrinal) would work in any other environment. I think it's just this application that maybe needs some bespoke method to be invoked. I will investigate. Thank you both though

Comment: @jbab8 - You are welcome :) When you solve it please let us know if possible - it is interesting

Comment: When on windows always keep system restart and Visual studio restart as possible options in the armour, always handy, all the very best :)

Comment: @GiladGreen It appears to be an issue with the vendor's SDK, rather than the code itself. I successfully tested it outside of the SDK without an issue as did the vendor...

Answer (score 3):

Another option will result in `DataRow`, from which any relevant `Column` can be selected, provided its not `Null`

```
var dataRow =   dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(row => row.Field<string>("id") == class.ID)
                            .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<double>("verlabel"))
                            .FirstOrDefault();

var result = dataRow?["ColumnName"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
var res = dt.AsEnumerable().where(a => a.Field<String>("id") == class.ID).Select(b => b.Field<double>>("verlabel").Max();
```