# Escape block bracket in .Select

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, escaping

I am trying filter the data out of a `DataTable` using the `Select` function

```
Dim dr() As DataRow = Nothing
Dim DtDataSource As DataTable

'value is populated here in DataTable (12,000 Records)

dr = DtDataSource.Select("[Name] like '[PAPER]*'") 'Gives Error
```

The error is thrown at the last line where I try to get data from the DataTable because I am using block brackets **'['** and **']'**.

In **C#** we could use the following code to get around it

```
dr = DtDataSource.Select("[Name] like '\[PAPER\]*' ESCAPE '\\'");
```

But if I use the same concept here, it gives the following error

> Syntax error: Missing operand after 'ESCAPE' operator.

Now is there anyway through which I can get the data out of DataTable which start with the phrase **[PAPER]**?

Comment: try looking at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_character_escapes.htm

Comment: @Mederic thanks for the reply but i do not understand how a block bracket can be used in any of the cases listed in the website

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable, it migth help you solving your problem

Comment: why not to use `lambda expression`?

Comment: sorry but i am new to VB.NET, can anyone show me how to use it in my case?

Comment: Are you certain that the [] were preserved when the table column was named?

Comment: @CDove yes sir the record was populated from SQL to the DataTable and then i use [] to search for the records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Escape the square brackets in this way

```
 dr = DtDataSource.Select("[Name] like '[[]PAPER[]]%'")
```

An alternative is to use LINQ to extract the information from your DataTable

```
 rows = DtDataSource.AsEnumerable().
                     Where(Function(row) row.Field(OfType String)("Name").
                     StartsWith("[PAPER]")

 .... work with the datarow collection
 For Each row as DataRow in rows
    .....
 Next
```

Comment: Not working? Please explain, same error message or it simply doesn't return the records expected?

Comment: By the way, you say _records with ends with the word [PAPER]_ but, as is, the query searches records that START with the word [PAPER], if you want [PAPER] at the end of the column you should move the wildcard before [PAPER]

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote at the end

Comment: yeah that did the trick. By mistake i used the wrong sequence of brackets

Comment: Good, however, if the search of these records could be isolated in the context I suggest to change the query that populates the DataTable to work only with the searched records returned by the database engine and not with runtime subselection of the DataTable content.

Answer (score 0):

did you notice that your `DataRow` is an array of data rows? you declare: `Dim dr() As DataRow = Nothing` and not `Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing` (just making sure).
 if you need a multiple rows that contains the string [Paper] use the third example and extract all the rows to a new `DataTable`.
 if you need just one distinct row use the first \ second example. you can achieve the same result with [linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)\ [lambda expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-lambda-expression):

```
Public Sub ex2()
    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim DtDataSource As DataTable

    ' 1. example with linq'
    dr = (From row In DtDataSource.AsEnumerable()
          Where row.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains("[PAPER]") Select row).FirstOrDefault()
    ' 2. example with lambda expiration'    
    dr = DtDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains("[PAPER]")).Select(Function(y) y).FirstOrDefault()

    ' 3. but if you want all the rows that containes [Paper] you can do it like that:'
    Dim tempDt As DataTable = DtDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains("[PAPER]")).Select(Function(y) y).CopyToDataTable()
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course also using Linq is a good approach, but please notice "SingleOrDefault" will throw if there are more than one matching record (very probable with a LIKE statement). Perhaps it is better FirstOrDefault. In any case Single/FirstOrDefault could be used with a lambda expression removing the necessity of the Where. Finally in the linq-to-objects examples you don't need to Select

Comment: @Steve thanks probably `FirstOrDefault` is better, edited the answer. also example 3 is for multiple rows  (very probable with a LIKE statement)