# Populating DataGridView Using LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **DataGridView** with a source of DataSet filled by Adapter using data from Database. Now I want to query the DataSet with closed connection. What is the query to search a specific record?

This is the code that fetches all customers:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet CustList = new DataSet();
    CustList = gt.GetCustomers();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = CustList.Tables[0];
}
```

What will be done to query this DataSet `CustList` and throw the results back in the same DGV, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
select myRow;
```

[[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)