# Retrieving data from datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to retrieve a `username` from a `DataTable` by `UserID` using `LINQ` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable#) example.

```
//Example 1:
var user = (from dr in users.AsEnumerable()
               where dr.Field<int>("UserID") == 2
               select dr).First();
//Example 2:
string user = (from dr in users.AsEnumerable()
               where dr.Field<int>("UserID") == 3
               select dr.Field<string>("UserName")).First();
```

The above two examples are causing this cast error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

However, the query does work if my `where clause` searches by `string` instead of `int`.

```
string result = (from row in users.AsEnumerable()
                 where row.Field<string>("UserName") == "TUser"
                 select row.Field<string>("UserName")).First();
```

How do I retrieve the single username by userid?

**UPDATE:**

Not sure if it's relevant, but the datatable is getting populated by desirializing `.json` file using `JSON.NET`

A sample `.json`

> [{
>           "UserID": 2,
>           "UserName": "User",
>           "StatusID": 1,
>           "CreateDate": "2018-04-25T14:02:00",
>           "CreateBy": "Admin",
>           "ID": "9855626A-FEF1-4936-9EF6-DD896F80AE35"
>       }, {
>           "UserID": 3,
>           "UserName": "TUser",
>           "StatusID": 1,
>           "CreateDate": "2018-04-25T14:02:00",
>           "CreateBy": "Admin",
>           "ID": "928D6099-0665-4FC8-BE4C-8E145E56E8BF"
>       }
>   ]

And populating datatable:

```
DataTable users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(File.ReadAllText(userPath));
```

Comment: What is the underlying type of `UserID`, then?

Comment: It's an integer.

Comment: Use _dr.Field<long>("UserID").._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the right datatype for `UserID` column

Check your UserID's column type in DB and use the following table

```
BigInt -> long
int -> int
SmallInt -> short
varchar/nvarchar -> string
```

Comment: I have confirmed that the `UserID` is stored in DB as `int`.

Comment: @smr5 how about users.Columns["UserID"].DataType and is it nullable?

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: @smr5 you haven't answer the question. Whats the .DataType output for the DataTable?

Comment: I was checking that...I'm very surprised with the output! `{Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}`, since the data is stored in DB as int, yet it's converting to `Int64`.

Comment: I have learned something new today. Thank you!  My educated guess is that `JSON.NET` converted the type during deserialization or when I was actually creating json file from db.