# Select top 1 from DataTable where column order by Column as string

Tags: c#, datatable

[image: See the picture of sample results that I need to parse]

See the **C#** Datatable's values above. I need to get the **highlighted** value, based on colA, and dateof, which I could explain with SQL, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 colB FROM dt WHERE colA = 'aaa' ORDER BY dateof ASC
```

I have to do it in **C#**, not in SQL.

How can I get that value?

Comment: `I have to do it in C#, not in SQL.` Why?

Comment: [Linq query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here: Sorting rows in a data table" not even close to the answer from sujith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try the following code and let me know whether it helps or not? 
Let `myDataTable`,be the DataTable that you are processing, assume that the type of field is `string`(change appropriately if needed)

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(x => x.Field<string>("colA") == "aaa")
           .OrderBy(y => y.Field<string>("dateof"))
           .Take(1)
           .Select(s => s.Field<string>("colB"))
```

Or else this may help you:

```
var defaultSelectedRow = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("colA") == "aaa")
                                    .OrderBy(y => y.Field<string>("dateof")).FirstOrDefault();
if (defaultSelectedRow != null)
{
    string colBValue = defaultSelectedRow.Field<string>("colB");
}
```

Comment: The second one is perfect. Thank you for your help. I have seen the "select" part in a few places, I have seen the "take(1)" part in a few places, and I have seen the DataTable ordering in a few places, but your answer has all of them together. Great help!