# Create a DataTable containing only unique values with Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable `dt_Candidates`

```
      Candidate      |   First Name   |   Last Name   
 --------------------|----------------|--------------- 
  John, Kennedy      | John           | Kennedy       
  Richard, Nixon     | Richard        | Nixon         
  Eleanor, Roosevelt | Eleanor        | Roosevelt     
  Jack, Black        | Jack           | Black         
  Richard, Nixon     | Richard        | Nixon
```

I want to create without a nested loops and preferably using Linq, a DataTable containing **ONLY** unique values like this one called `dt_Candidates2`:

```
      Candidate      |   First Name   |   Last Name   
 --------------------|----------------|--------------- 
  John, Kennedy      | John           | Kennedy       
  Eleanor, Roosevelt | Eleanor        | Roosevelt     
  Jack, Black        | Jack           | Black
```

And a list or an array called `RejectedCandidates` containing the distinct duplicates

```
RejectedCandidates = {"Richard, Nixon"}
```

Comment: Do you want to enforce uniqueness based on the `Candidate` column?

Comment: I don't think LINQ is a good tool for this; add a primary key to the table and adjust the logic that creates the table to use it (or catch the error thrown when adding a repeated value)

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, I do! As far as the whole logic goes, I just changed my mind another time... Another workaround could be creating the RejectedCandidates and when facing the ForEach loop to work on the single value checking `RejectedCandidates.Any(row("Candidate").ToString.Contains)` so it won't work `RejectedCandidates` and it can provide a viable feedback...

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for your useful tips! I'm still very new to C# and I used found Linq to be very handy, I think my logic has been faulted by the mere-exposure effect! :)

Comment: One of my favorite sayings is "LINQ is a hammer.. but not every problem is a nail" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, I don't think it really needs LINQ here. It can go something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Candidate");
dt.Columns.Add("First");
dt.Columns.Add("Last");
dt.PrimaryKey = new []{ dt.Columns["Candidate"] }; //means that dt.Find() will work

while(...){
  string candidate = ...

  if(dt.Rows.Find(candidate) != null)
    RejectList.Add(...);
  else
    dt.Rows.Add(...);
}
```

Avoid using LINQ's `.Any` on a DataTable for this. Not only is it a pain to get going because it needs casting steps or extension libraries ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable))  to, it will then use loops to find the info you seek; the built-in mechanism for the PrimaryKey uses hash tables for much faster lookups.

Comment: adding PrimaryKey to a table with duplicates throws `System.ArgumentException: These columns don't currently have unique values` or  `System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'Candidate' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'Richard, Nixon' is already present` depending on when rows are added (before or after PK). am I missing smth in your solution?

Comment: You're supposed to add the PK to a table that doesn't have duplicates. The code in the answer makes a new table, adds columns, adds a key and then fills the table. As it is filling it is checking `if` the value is present and if it is, it is putting the value into the reject list instead. In other words; whatever code you have that fills a table with duplicates, replace it with this notion

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = new DataTable
{
    Columns = {"Candidate", "First Name", "Last Name"},
    Rows = 
    {
        new object [] { "John, Kennedy", "John", "Kennedy"},
        new object [] { "Richard, Nixon", "Richard", "Nixon"},
        new object [] { "Eleanor, Roosevelt", "Eleanor", "Roosevelt"},
        new object [] { "Jack, Black", "Jack", "Black"},
        new object [] { "Richard, Nixon", "Richard", "Nixon"},
    }
};
```

you can use grouping (groupBy) to find duplicates, filter them out, and then create a new DataTable, using [DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=net-5.0) extension method:

```
var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()

            .GroupBy(r => r["Candidate"])
            .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)

            .Select(g => g.First())
            .CopyToDataTable();
```